# Pandas replace last item in groupby if NaN with another colum

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to replace the last row in a group by with the value of another column only if it is null. I am able to do both of these pieces separately but can't seem to combine them. Anyone have any ideas?

These are the separate pieces:

```
# replace any NaN values with values from 'target'
df.loc[df['target'].isnull(),'target'] = df['value']

# replace last value in groupby with value from 'target'
df.loc[df.groupby('id').tail(1).index,'target'] = df['value']
```

Original Data:

```
    date        id      value       target
0   2020-08-07  id01    0.100775    NaN
1   2020-08-08  id01    0.215885    0.215885
2   2020-08-09  id01    0.012154    0.012154
3   2020-08-10  id01    0.374503    NaN
4   2020-08-07  id02    0.369707    0.369707
5   2020-08-08  id02    0.676743    0.676743
6   2020-08-09  id02    0.659521    0.659521
7   2020-08-10  id02    0.799071    NaN
```

Replace 'target' column with last row in groupby('id') with what is in 'value':

```
    date        id      value       target
0   2020-08-07  id01    0.100775    NaN
1   2020-08-08  id01    0.215885    0.215885
2   2020-08-09  id01    0.012154    0.012154
3   2020-08-10  id01    0.374503    0.374503
4   2020-08-07  id02    0.369707    0.369707
5   2020-08-08  id02    0.676743    0.676743
6   2020-08-09  id02    0.659521    0.659521
7   2020-08-10  id02    0.799071    0.799071
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do. Added the `tail` variable just for easier to read syntaxis:

```
tail = df.groupby('id').tail(1)
df.loc[tail.index,'target'] = df.loc[tail.index]['target'].fillna(tail.value)
```

Output:

```
0 idx        date    id     value    target
1   0  2020-08-07  id01  0.100775       NaN
2   1  2020-08-08  id01  0.215885  0.215885
3   2  2020-08-09  id01  0.012154  0.012154
4   3  2020-08-10  id01  0.374503  0.374503
5   4  2020-08-07  id02  0.369707  0.369707
6   5  2020-08-08  id02  0.676743  0.676743
7   6  2020-08-09  id02  0.659521  0.659521
8   7  2020-08-10  id02  0.799071  0.799071
```

Answer (score 3):

`fillna` on the entire column but mask back to `NaN` if it's a missing that isn't the last for each 'id'.

```
m = df['target'].isnull() & df['id'].duplicated(keep='last')
df['target'] = df['target'].fillna(df['value']).mask(m)
```

---

```
         date    id     value    target
0  2020-08-07  id01  0.100775       NaN
1  2020-08-08  id01  0.215885  0.215885
2  2020-08-09  id01  0.012154  0.012154
3  2020-08-10  id01  0.374503  0.374503
4  2020-08-07  id02  0.369707  0.369707
5  2020-08-08  id02  0.676743  0.676743
6  2020-08-09  id02  0.659521  0.659521
7  2020-08-10  id02  0.799071  0.799071
```

Answer (score 1):

With combine_first, you are spoiled for choices.

**First option**

Use `.groupby()` with `nth(value)`

```
m=df.groupby('id',as_index=False).nth(-1).index#mask each last value in the group
df.loc[m, 'target'] = df['target'].combine_first(df['value'])populate value
```

**Second Option**

Use `combine_first` using `.iloc` accessor to get the last values in the `target` column and `value` column in a one line `groupby`

```
     df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:(x.iloc[-1:,3].combine_first(x.iloc[-1:,2])))\
.reset_index(level=0).combine_first(df)
```

**Third Option**

Select the last index in each group. Populate column target as required and update df using combine_first

```
g=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:x.iloc[-1:]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
#df.loc[g, 'target'] = df['target'].combine_first(df['value'])
g.target=g.value
g.combine_first(df)



   date    id     value    target
0  2020-08-07  id01  0.100775       NaN
1  2020-08-08  id01  0.215885  0.215885
2  2020-08-09  id01  0.012154  0.012154
3  2020-08-10  id01  0.374503  0.374503
4  2020-08-07  id02  0.369707  0.369707
5  2020-08-08  id02  0.676743  0.676743
6  2020-08-09  id02  0.659521  0.659521
7  2020-08-10  id02  0.799071  0.799071
```

Comment: @dingo was this helpful? Happy to help further

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the last **target** inside `groupby()` and then replace only null values using `.combine_first()`

```
indexes = df.groupby('id').tail(1).index
df.loc[indexes, 'target'] = df['target'].combine_first(df['value'])
#result
    date        id      value       target
0   2020-08-07  id01    0.100775    NaN
1   2020-08-08  id01    0.215885    0.215885
2   2020-08-09  id01    0.012154    0.012154
3   2020-08-10  id01    0.374503    0.374503
4   2020-08-07  id02    0.369707    0.369707
5   2020-08-08  id02    0.676743    0.676743
6   2020-08-09  id02    0.659521    0.659521
7   2020-08-10  id02    0.799071    0.799071
```